# Славяне, Словакия, Словения

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Задумалась об этих, так похожих друг на друга словах.
Правда, сам собой напрашивается вывод, что слово "славяне" происходит от слова "славный", а вот "Словакия" и "Словения" - от "слово". Хотя это только поверхностное впечатление.
Но интересно было бы узнать, родственны ли эти слова между собой, а еще другое: славянских племен, как известно, было много и все они назывались по-разному. Но кто же все-таки назывался именно славянами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Именно "славянами" ("словянами", "словенами") назывались **все** племена, говорящие "словом" (группа родственных языков, носители которых понимали друг друга без перевода). Рёкшие "речью" (любой язык, не понятный славянам) - назывались "немцами"

Answer (score 1):

"Слово" и "слава" – слова родственные, по сути даже одно, которое просто разошлось в произношении, потом написании и значении на два. Славяне ("словѣне") – это "говорящие", те, которые говорят на понятном языке, в отличии от "немых" немцев.

Comment: Думаю "немцы" - это, всё-таки, не "немые", а "не мы"

Answer (score 1):

Всё верно, но немцев лучше не трогать. Немцами называли только германцев. Остальных же называли иначе и по-разному. Есть старое предположение, что слово "немцы" происходит от названия германского племени неметов. Эти неметы отражены в римских хрониках. Не ясно только одно: откуда предки русских их так хорошо знали. Видимо они "пересекались" ещё до римлян. А так, всё понятно: неметы - неметский - немецкий - немцы. 
На Украине до сих пор Германию  называют как-то вроде "Неметчина" (Нимеччина).

Comment: Появление  слова  относится  ко  времени  общеславянского  единства.  Римляне  здесь  ни  при  чём.  Спасибо  им,  что  в  хрониках  отразили   этот  этноним.

Answer (score 1):

НЕМЕЦ (этимологический словарь **Крылова**)
Один из редких случаев, когда за народом закрепляется название, данное ему как бы по недоразумению, ведь образовано это слово от причастия нем – "непонятно говорящий"; так на Руси называли когда-то всех чужестранцев, чей язык был непонятен местным жителям. Впоследствии так стали называть лишь выходцев из Германии. 
**Из Фасмера** «С названием зап.-герм. неметов (Плиний, Тацит; см. Мух у Хоопса, Reall. 3, 301 и сл.) у Шпейера слав. nemьcь не имеет ничего общего по фонетическим и географическим соображениям, вопреки Шахматову (AfslPh 33, 82 и сл.), Беличу (ИОРЯС 8, 2, 388), Микколе (Zschr. f. d. Wf. 6, 372; Этногр. Обозр. 60, 178; РФВ 48, 270 и сл.); ср. Фасмер, RS 6, 194; Ягич, AfslPh 31, 591; Янко, Teuthonista 8, 127 и сл.; WuS 1, 108; ZfslPh 13, 417 и сл.; Клюге, Zschr. f. d. Wf. 6, 372 и сл.; Грюненталь, там же; Улашин, там же.»

Comment: Лично меня "неметская" теория больше впечатляет, т.к. нет никаких оснований закреплять только за германцами название "непонятно говорящие". Ближайшие соседи-финны говорят ещё непонятнее. Если у русского и германского языков есть общий базис, то с финским вообще ничего общего нет.